# GWT in Firefox41 repetitively encodes token in URL

Tags: firefox, gwt

Gwt Application with Place, Activities etc.

Has anyone else encountered Firefox 41.0 repetitively encoding % in the token of URL - looks like when PlaceController goto() is called? Loops until it crashes!!
Token starts out with pipes: #search:advanced|FOO|001|false

Encoded to #search:advanced%7CFOO%7C001%7Cfalse

Chrome opens it perfectly, but latest Firefox starts looping, adding an extra 25 (repetitively encoding the % ??)....

Example (from logger): INFO: Tokenized searchPlace: SearchPlace: searchType:advanced%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525257CFOO%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525257C001%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525257Cfalse%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525257C%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525257C%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525257Cfalse%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525[…]

Did NOT happen in previous version of Firefox - only when we upgraded to 41.0 last weekend! Have checked out the add-ons ... no luck.

Tried messing with the standard-url settings in about:config ... also no luck.

Have gotten around it by adding application code to "decodeURIComponent" when the user.agent contains "gecko" every time getPlace() is called .... but surely there is an easier fix - is it a setting in Firefox that got reset?

Answer (score 3):

Go to:

> about > config

Then search for:

> dom.url.getters_decode_hash;

and change its value to  `true`

Comment: You are a star!! Thank you so much! Problem sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating here an answer to a similar question in GWT forum: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/3-qX9x7nfJM/7zeBR2daBAAJ

> This has been fixed in GWT 2.7.0. We refactored the history implementation to not special case Firefox in this particular way. Just updating to GWT 2.7 will fix this issue for you.
>
> If that is not possible here is the main patch to make history work:
>   https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/5356/

Answer (score 1):

It is problem of History implementation of older GWT, workaround is put replace configuration to your App.gwt.xml

```
<replace-with class="com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImplSafari">
<when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl"/>
<when-property-is name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>
</replace-with>
```

Comment: This works only if you use FF41+. If you need to support also older version, then you need to create your own implementation that switches depending on the FF version.

Comment: Problem is only on FF41+ so for older version you do not need to handle workaround, we tested it on FF 23+