# GWT Application not working since Firefox 41

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, gwt, smartgwt

I've developed a GWT application which works as expected during the development in Firefox 26. It also works as expected with the latest Chrome and with Firefox till version 40.

Since Firefox 41 I am facing an issue, which causes an overlay of the entire page. (Calling the application with the entire URL [contains get parameters] prevent loading the page successfully and show a blank page).

The application looks freezed and the following line was added at the end of the body tag:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2147483647;"></div>
```

z-index: 2147483647 is on top of the page and deny all kind of interactions. Removing it with FireBug and the application works quite well.

GWT: 2.6.1
GWTP: 0.7
SmartGWT: 4.0
gflot: 3.3.0

During my investigation I have not found any hints why it is not working with Firefox 41 or higher.

gwt.xml:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" values="gecko1_8" />
```

Any idea?

Comment: FYI, you may want to update to GWT 2.7 (2.8 is about to be released BTW): https://stackoverflow.com/q/32840678/116472

Answer (score 1):

After implementing the hotfix for the issue no "script" tags in gwt.xml are allowed, GWT 2.7 works and there is no more Firefox issue.

Thx, for the hint.